# how can i solve this error in my program?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, syntax-error

i got this error "IndexError: index 60 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 60"
and i dont know hot to solve it any suggestion? im using numpy as np and pygame

```
size = width , height = 600,600

nx =60                                // i think the problem it in this values
ny=60
dimX = (width-1) / nx
dimY = (height-1) / ny
white=(255,255,255)

backG = 25 , 25 , 25

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)



screen.fill(backG)

GameState = np.zeros((nx,ny))

while 1 :

        for y in range(1,ny+1):
                for x in range(1,nx+1):


                        n_neigh = GameState[(x-1)%nx,(y-1)%ny] + GameState[(x)%nx,(y-1)%ny] + \
                                GameState[(x+1)%nx,(y-1)%ny] + GameState[(x-1)%nx,(y)%ny] + \
                                GameState[(x+1)%nx,(y)%ny] + GameState[(x-1)%nx,(y+1)%ny] + \
                                GameState[(x)%nx,(y+1)%ny] + GameState[(x+1)%nx,(y+1)%ny]
                        #R 1
                        if GameState[x,y] == 0 and n_neigh==3:
                                GameState[x,y] = 1
                        #R
                        elif GameState[x,y] == 1 and (n_neigh < 2 or nNeigh > 3):
                                 GameState[x,y] = 0 // and with this operations
```

i cannot undertand what its wrong there

Comment: You really should name your variables better.

Comment: Python list indexes start at zero.  A list with 60 elements has valid indexes from 0 to 59.  Index 60 is actually the 61st item, which is out of bounds.

Comment: try doing `for y in range(1,ny)` and `for x in range(1,nx)`

Comment: as per John Gordon, however you then index x+1 x-1 and y+1 y-1 so your ranges need to be range(1,nx-1). Also you have a typo at ```nNeigh```.